Cookie not appearing in dev tools, or being sent it requests even though set-cookie is in the response header
I have a react frontend running on port 5173 and a node js backend on port 5000. I have a login form that logs in and the response has a set-cookie with a token. However the cookie does not appear in the dev tools Application->Storage->Cookies, neither is it present in subsequent requests.
Cors set up
app.use(cors({
  origin: 'http://localhost:5173',
  credentials: true, 
}));

cookies creation
  res.cookie('token', authToken.token, {
    httpOnly: false,//false just for testing
    secure:false, 
    sameSite: 'None',
    maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 168, // 1 week
    path: '/'
  })

frontend call after login
const response = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/api/auth/check', {
        method: 'GET',
        credentials: 'include', 
      });

checking for cookie on request
console.log(req.cookies);

results in [Object: null prototype] {}
I feel the issue must be early on since the cookie does not show in the dev tools, but I'm not sure why since it is in the response. Here is the response after the login function is called
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: Express
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:5173
Vary: Origin
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Set-Cookie: token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6ODMyMjMzNjk0LCJhY2Nlc3MiOjEsImlhdCI6MTcyODE0NDE2NiwiZXhwIjoxNzI4NzQ4OTY2fQ.F83l7VGYvZLcYXY6gaFQmezd9TuCIDQIv0JRySaA9qI; Max-Age=604800; Path=/; Expires=Sat, 12 Oct 2024 16:02:46 GMT; SameSite=None
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 43
ETag: W/"2b-L/lj66ZG7Ci3fY6guTi0ymZXOqc"
Date: Sat, 05 Oct 2024 16:02:46 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=5

I've tried changing the cors config around and the cookie properties but still nothing. The set-cookie is there in the response but it goes no further than that. I've seen other questions on this and believe I have tried everything, but maybe I have been fixing one issue and breaking something else.

I suspect its related to sameSite being none which in some browsers (chrome) also requires secure: true which in turn means you need https -- including on local dev env. However, before going down that road, you don't have cross origin here (both are localhost and the different port doesn't count as different host in regards to cookies), so why not use sameSite: 'lax'?

Unrelated but you should still have httpOnly: true even when debugging. Those can still be viewed in dev tools. Only thing it blocks is reading them in the JS (which you don't want to do).

@adsy I have tried lax as well as httpOnly:true, in the above code it was just false as I saw somewhere that you might not be able to see the cookie in dev tools if it was true. I've just been trying to lower the security as much as possible to rule everything out.

I have found the reason, credentials: 'include', needs to also be on the original login call not just the subsequent calls.
